# CSS Animation Transform a div into another

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to code an animation that transforms one div into another.

For example, if I want to transform div1 into div2, I'd like div1 to get the size, position, rotation and background color of div2.

Here is my first code (without any animation) :

https://jsfiddle.net/53yr7usq/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
.center {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
#div1 {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
#div2 {
    position:absolute;
    left:-30px;
    bottom:10px;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 80px;
    height: 120px;
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
</style>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="center">
            <div id="div1">
                <h1>
                    DIV1
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="div2">
            <h1>
                DIV2
            </h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So after...

I tried to create an animation with keyframes, but it's not fluid at all (there's a jump and the movement isn't fluid).

https://jsfiddle.net/dnwarojb/2/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
.center {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
#div1 {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    animation: transformation 2s infinite;
}
#div2 {
    position:absolute;
    left:-30px;
    bottom:10px;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 80px;
    height: 120px;
    transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
@keyframes transformation {
    100% {
        position:absolute;
        left:-30px;
        bottom:10px;
        width: 80px;
        height: 120px;
        background-color: blue;
        transform: rotate(-10deg);
    }
}
</style>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="center">
            <div id="div1">
                <h1>
                    DIV1
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="div2">
            <h1>
                DIV2
            </h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Finally, I thought of using a transform translate but I don't know how to determine the pixels to translate....

https://jsfiddle.net/9egh5unf/3/

```html
<style>
:root {
--x:-10px;
--y:10px;
}
@keyframes transformation {
    100% {
        width: 80px;
        height: 120px;
        background-color: blue;
        transform: rotate(-10deg) translate(var(--x),var(--y));
    }
}
</style>
<script>
function gap() {
    div1 = "div1"
    div2 = "div2"
    w1_rotate = document.getElementById(div1).getBoundingClientRect().width;
    w1_droit = document.getElementById(div1).clientWidth;
    w_cut = (w1_rotate - w1_droit) / 2

    po_x_2 = (window.innerWidth - w1_rotate) / 2
    
    translate_x = w_cut + po_x_2 + 129.5
    
    h1_rotate = document.getElementById(div1).getBoundingClientRect().height;
    h1_droit = document.getElementById(div1).clientHeight;
    h_cut = (h1_rotate - h1_droit) / 2

    po_y_2 = document.getElementById(div2).getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
    po_y_1 = document.getElementById(div1).getBoundingClientRect().bottom;

    translate_y = po_y_1 - po_y_2 + h_cut

    console.log(translate_x)
    console.log(translate_y)
    //Change CSS Variable with the new translate_x and translate_y
}
</script>
```

But here again I have a problem: the number of pixels I'm calculating isn't right, so my translation is wrong...

So I'd like to know if there's a way of transforming div1 into div2, either without jumping in the animation, or with the right number of pixels for translation.

Thanks a lot!

**-- Summary of what I tried to do --**

So, has I said, I tried to create an animation but it wasn't fluid/smooth... So I decided to use a `transform : translate()` to make it smoother but I don't arrive to find the good X_translation and the good Y_translation

Comment: I added jsfiddle link to illustrate my issue (hope it's easier to understand it...)

Answer (score 0):

You should change your **keyframe** you should have a 0% too. you should say what you want to change in 100% block code.

Comment: Even with a 0% it didn't work, it still avec a jump : https://jsfiddle.net/8odj62gh/

Answer (score 0):

It seems the principal issue was that div1 was not using absolute positioning like div2, if you change div1 to use absolute positioning with left and bottom, exactly as div2, it doesn't jump anymore: https://jsfiddle.net/carolhmj/sbtocmqd/6/. I'm not 100% sure what should happen in the browser when animating from an non-absolute to an absolute position, but it's probably best to avoid this from happening on the first place.

In the fiddle, div1 is:

```
#div1 {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    left: 260px;
    bottom: 260px;
    animation: transformation 2s infinite;
  }
```